# Excel VBA Date Save - run time error 75 path/file access error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

im getting the following error message when i run this code that lets me make folders if they don't exist to save files in them: "run time error 75 path/file access error"

any thoughts?

```
Sub auto_organize_save1()
    Dim fdObj As Object
    Dim folder As String
    
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    folderYear = "C:\temp\testing\" & Format(Now, "YYYY") & "\"
    folderMonth = "C:\temp\testing\" & Format(Now, "YYYY") & "\" & Format(Now, "MM-MMM") & "\"
    
    
    
    If Not fdObj.FolderExists(folder) Then
        MkDir folderYear
    End If
    
        If Not fdObj.FolderExists(folder) Then
        MkDir folderMonth
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=folderMonth & "example.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: First bulletpoint of the docco? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/path-file-access-error-error-75

Comment: So im getting the error code under the first IF statement. this is the line that gets highlighted during debugging "MkDir folderYear"

the issue only occurs when the folders exist, when they don't exist it runs perfectly

Comment: Do you assign `folder` anywhere before calling `.FolderExists(folder)`?

Comment: Also, you already have the directory for the year, no need to repeat it: `folderMonth = folderYear & Format(Now, "MM-MMM") & "\"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if `folder` exists, not `folderYear` and/or `folderMonth`.

Try

```
If Not fdObj.FolderExists(folderYear) Then
    MkDir folderYear
End If

If Not fdObj.FolderExists(folderMonth) Then
    MkDir folderMonth
End If
```

Also, you might want to add in a check that the folder called ***testing*** exists.